# Passing variables through handlebars blockhelper

Tags: handlebars.js, partials

I want to pass and compile params in my custom block helper. I found out that the params are inside a hash-object, but how can I compile them into the partial?

I want the param `flyoutClass` to be compiled into my partial. Everything works fine but the place where the output of my param should be stays empty...

handlebars helper

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, context)  { 
    Handlebars.registerHelper('injectHtml', function(name, options) {
        console.log(options.hash); //yeah my param
        var partial = Handlebars.partials[name];
        var template = Handlebars.compile(partial);
        //var template = Handlebars.compile(partial)(options.hash); *
        var output = template({"body":  options.fn(this)});     
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(output); 
        //return new Handlebars.SafeString(output(options.hash)); *
        //return new Handlebars.SafeString(partial(output)); *
    }) 
};
```

I have already tried some things, but I always get that warning...

> Warning: string is not a function

.hbs file

```
<div class="flyout {{flyoutClass}}">
    <button>flyout-button</button>
    <div class="flyout__content">
        {{{body}}}
    </div> 
</div>
```

call my blockhelper

```
{{#injectHtml "flyout" flyoutClass='navigation__item'}}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>some copy</p>
        <button>CTA</button>
    </div
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>some copy</p>
        <button>CTA</button>
    </div>
{{/injectHtml}}
```

**UPTADE**

And is it possible to pass from my blockhelper a param to another partial?

```
var output = template({
    "addClass": options.hash.addClass,
    "id": options.hash.id,
    "body": options.fn(this)
});
```

I like to extend this partial with "id"

```
{{#injectHtml "flyout" flyoutClass='navigation__item'id='myUniqueID'}}
```

and also use it in my partial button

```
<div class="flyout {{flyoutClass}}">
    {{>button btn="icon-text" id="{{id}}"/*[1]*/ icon="arrow-down"label="klick me"}}
    <div class="flyout__content" aria-labelledby="{{id}}"/*[2]*/> 
        {{{body}}}
    </div> 
</div>
```

But at [1] the param isn't compiled, [2] works fine.

```
<div class="flyout navigation__item">
    <a href="#" id="{{id}}"/*[1]*/ aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="flyout__content" aria-labelledby="myUniqueID"/*[2]*/> 
        //html content
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "compile" the `flyoutClass` parameter into the partial template because you are intending this parameter to be dynamic. This means it is really just another parameter of your template data:

```
var output = template({
    "flyoutClass": options.hash.flyoutClass,
    "body": options.fn(this)
});
```

**UPDATE**

> ... but there is no way to add the params dynamicly??[sic]

If you wish to pass along all of the parameters passed to your helper, you could simply extend a template data object within your helper with the `options.hash`:

```
var data = Handlebars.Utils.extend({ body: options.fn(this) }, options.hash);
var output = template(data);
```

Comment: WOW thank you ;) that works, but there is no way to add the params dynamicly?? Because i also want to use this blockhelper as a generell helper for other partials like my fakescroller, dropdown,..